# Is there any way to copy one scratch org to another?

Tags: scratch-org

I am trying to find a way to copy all the data and custom settings, etc from one scratch org to another. I have one org with a lot of custom setting, custom metadata and also need to do manually set up for communities. The problem is every month we need to do is there any way I can just copied one org to another so I don't have to do this every month?

Answer (score 3):

The feature that does this (Org Snapshot) is still in pilot and is not generally available.

But more generally, it sounds like you've been pushed by some of the complexities of your application into using scratch orgs in a way they're not really designed for. If you're using a scratch org for 30 days every 30 days, you're not taking advantage of the nature of the org as a disposable, repeatable, clean environment.

I think you have two options.

- One is to use a persistent org. I'll never really recommend this - scratch orgs are the future! - but at present, you're almost using scratch orgs like persistent orgs, except that you're doing a lot of work to facilitate that use case by repeating setup.
- The other, and the one I strongly prefer, is to build out comprehensive automation to set up your scratch orgs so that they *can* be truly disposable. There's multiple ways to do this. You can take advantage of the wide ecosystem of SFDX plugins that can automate setup and load data, and build out scripting to join these together.

  Because I am on the team that builds it and wrote the [trail](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/trails/build-applications-with-cumulusci)
  (disclaimer!) I'll encourage you to check out CumulusCI, though. It
  builds on Salesforce DX to provide comprehensive scratch org setup, including data seeding.

I've yet to find any tool, though, that truly makes it easy to set up Communities in scratch orgs with all the bells and whistles.

Comment: Even force:data:tree:import can be used for most use cases involving data, as long as they're not trying to literally recreate the data in production.

Answer (score 1):

No, scratch orgs are always empty when created afresh. They're meant to be populated with metadata from your source code repository, which is the purpose of Salesforce DX. Source Code (in the source code version control) is the truth. So make sure the finalized code (apex class/custom metadata/custom setting) all needs to be tested and checked-in to the source version control.

Answer (score 1):

For now there is no way to clone the scratch org, except salesforce made this feature as GA

> force:org:shape:create (Pilot)

Currently this will be only available for few customers to test from salesforce

But one alternative solution for save couple of hours for settings up all the stuff,

- For Custom Metadata you can retrieve the meta data from the org using sfdx force:source:retrieve commands
- For communities you can export the template and you can overwrite in your new scratch org, this will save your time while setting up of full community

and i don't have any solution for the custom settings

Comment: I think you're thinking of the Org Snapshot feature, not Org Shape. Org Snapshot clones.

Comment: @Yaswanth Tikkisetti what metadata can I get using this method? Can I get all accounts and contacts I created in original org?